# Inconsistency between 'uses' and 'Import-Package'

Tags: eclipse-plugin, osgi, osgi-bundle, bnd, bndtools

I am using bnd to generate `MANIFEST.MF` for a library.  In the end, I get a Manifest with the folllowing conflict:

```
Export-Package: A;uses:="B,C"
Import-Package: B
```

Package `A`, `B`, `C` all reside in separate plugins, also named `A`, `B`, and `C`.  At runtime, Eclipse does not load plugin `C`, and so I get a crash.  Also, the Eclipse tooling appears to only look at `Import-Package`, because the tooling is also unaware of the dependency on `C`.

Should `Import-Package` always contain all of the packages in the `uses` statement?  Is it an Eclipse bug, or (more likely) what am I doing wrong with bnd that's causing it to miss the dependency on C?

Comment: Can you provide the configuration you give to bnd?

Comment: I'm using a Gradle plugin called [unpuzzle](https://github.com/akhikhl/unpuzzle), which calls bnd for me automatically.  I haven't dug too deep into unpuzzle yet, because I'm not sure what the MANIFEST.MF is even *supposed* to look like.  My gut is that `Import-Package` should contain all of the `uses` directives, but I want to confirm that before I spend time digging into unpuzzle.

Comment: Without further details you will probably not get any useful answers. Can you provide a small project on github that shows your problem?

Answer (score 1):

For your question:

> Should Import-Package always contain all of the packages in the uses
>   statement? Is it an Eclipse bug, or (more likely) what am I doing
>   wrong with bnd that's causing it to miss the dependency on C?

The answer is: **No**.

With Importing you are declaring which packages your bundle needs, with exporting you declare which packages you give away to other bundles. The uses is a hint for the resolver that the Importing Bundle which needs package A will also need to import package B and C. 
This makes it easier on the resolving mechanism to find the appropriate bundles. Especially since the bundle that exports A does also need to import B but not C.

Clarifying question:

> It seems like Import-package ought to contain everything in uses, I'm
>   trying to understand a scenario where it wouldn't.

Bundle A is your bundle and exports package my.a.package
it uses package their.b.package from Bundle B and therefore Imports it. 
This is the simple stuff here. Now since you export my.a.package bnd analyzes also Bundle B for you. 
Since you aren't explicitly using any classes from Bundle C those aren't imported. 
But since bnd analyzed Bundle B for you it knows that packages from Bundle C are used as transitive dependency in B.

Comment: So if A uses B and C, but it only imports B, then how does it plan on getting C?

Comment: So what's the actual effect you're seeing? A ClassNotFound exception?

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: C` caused by `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C`.

Comment: I made a small test project that reproduces the issue, but the build is so deep (wuff calls unpuzzle calls BND makes the MANIFEST.MF for a 3rd party jar that I use, and this MANIFEST.MF has the category of problem I'm describing).  My goal is to understand how this MANIFEST.MF might make sense before I assume that it's wrong.  It seems like `Import-package` ought to contain everything in `uses`, I'm trying to understand a scenario where it wouldn't.

Comment: Interesting!  This feature seems like it defeats a lot of the whole point of interfaces, but it's very helpful to have some idea as to why `bnd` is generating this manifest.

Comment: I'd like to do more digging before I accept (in case I learn more that will be useful to future readers), but I think this answers my question.  Thanks!

Comment: Just to make it clear, uses doesn't mean import-package! The uses-constraint is only there to help the resolver of the framework to look into the "uses" direction for resolving dependencies. Nothing else.